# how to access input element in parent from inside iframe in sharepoint

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code and I have inserted it in an html page where I call it inside an iframe in a SharePoint page. I am using this line of code to get the id from the control in the parent page

```
var id = $('#prodId', window.parent.document).val()
```

but it is not working.

Any idea how to access objects in the parent page from within iframe?

```
  function formatItem(item) {
      return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
  }

  function find() {
      //var id = $('#prodId').val();
      var id = $('#prodId', window.parent.document).val()
      $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
          .done(function(data) {
              alert(formatItem(data));
              $('#product').text(formatItem(data));
          })
          .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
              alert(err);
              $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
          });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the page for the iFrame hosted? If you're in an app or in another domain, it won't work, [check out](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/iframe_talks_to_parent/%20for%20more%20details.)

Comment: it is hosted in a different domain/web application.

Comment: so there is really no way of accessing it

Comment: related: what are script app parts and how does Script Editor Webpart do this? are they embedded inline? Possible to develop a web part that works the same way? See my post.

Answer (score 1):

If it is in a different domain there are options (CORS) [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)